# "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0"

Tags: c#, json, parsing, anonymous, webinvoke

I use multiple APIs coded in C# that work well. I want to use one receiving an anonymous object (I don't want to create a Class). I have a problem when I try to deserialize the object.

I have an API following this scheme, it works well when it's called from `python` using the `json_dumps` function. But when I try with `JSON.stringify` (from an a or even POSTMAN, I have a 400 bad request.

Here is my code, I have tried a lot of things:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "myUrl")]
[OperationContract]
public Message myMethod(object objectSentByUser)
{
        
    var perso = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(objectSentByUser.ToString());
```

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>` waits for a string, I tried:

- to specify `objectSentByUser` as a string in the argument of `myMethod`
  When I do so, I've got a 400 without even entering the method (I tried to send a JSON, to add quotes, to send a string etc...)
- to cast with `(string)objectSentByUser`, it doesn't work
- to use the `toString()` method, which leads to the next error:

  > Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0

  which is quite normal because `objectSentByUser.toString()` returns "System.Object". But why does it work when used with python json_dump?

This code works when called with python function json_dump that returns an object like this:

```
"{\\\"key1\\\":\\\"value1\\\",...}"
```

From Postman I send a classic POST with `application/json` as `contentType` and valid `JSON` in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user sends a valid json string to your action, then don't accept an object as a parameter, but rather a string (i.e. because your user sends you one).

If you call `ToString()` on an object, chances are, it's not in a `Json` format.

Try accepting a string and deserializing that:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "myUrl")]
[OperationContract]
public Message myMethod(string jsonSentByUser)
{

    var perso = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonSentByUser);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

When I try the API thanks to POSTMAN with contentType application/json and a JSON object in the body, I receive a 400 bad request, I don't even enter myMethod.

It works when I send an object formatted this way:

"{\"key1\":\"value1\",...}"

Don't know why I tried with the python double backslashes and not with single backslashes..