# Youtube v3 API captions downloading

Tags: c#, .net, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to download captions from some videos on Youtube using their nuget package. Here's some code:

```
var request = _youtube.Search.List("snippet,id");
request.Q = "Bill Gates";
request.MaxResults = 50;
request.Type = "video";
var results = request.Execute();
foreach (var result in results.Items)
{
    var captionListRequest = _youtube.Captions.List("id,snippet", result.Id.VideoId);
    var captionListResponse = captionListRequest.Execute();
    var russianCaptions =
        captionListResponse.Items.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Snippet.Language.ToLower() == "ru");
    if (russianCaptions != null)
    {
        var downloadRequest = _youtube.Captions.Download(russianCaptions.Id);
        downloadRequest.Tfmt = CaptionsResource.DownloadRequest.TfmtEnum.Srt;
        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        downloadRequest.Download(ms);
    }
}
```

When the Download method is called I'm getting a weird Newtonsoft.JSON Exception that says:

```
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0.'
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
```

I've read some other threads on captions downloading problems and have tried to change my authorization workflow: first I've tried to use just the ApiKey but then also tried OAuth. Here's how it looks now:

```
 var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
    {
        ClientId = "CLIENT_ID",
        ClientSecret = "CLIENT_SECRET"
    },
    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("Youtube.CaptionsCrawler")).Result;

_youtube = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    ApplicationName = "LKS Captions downloader",
    HttpClientInitializer = credential
});
```

So, is it even possible to do what I'm trying to achieve?

P.S. I was able to dig deep into the youtube nuget package and as I see, the actual message, that I get (that Newtonsoft.JSON is trying to deserialize, huh!) is "*The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption.*"

So, do I have to be the video owner to download captions? But if so, how do other programs like [Google2SRT](https://sourceforge.net/projects/google2srt/?source=typ_redirect) work?

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362006/jsonreaderexception-unexpected-character-encountered), be noted that `JObject.Parse()` expects the actual JSON content (string), not a path. Also, converting JSON string to `JObject` and then back `ToString()` is really not adding any "value" here. You may also check these links: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23259173/unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263368/c-sharp-api-unexpected-character-encountered-while-parsing-value-s-path-l).

Comment: This Parse method is called INSIDE google's nuget package, that's why we can't do anything about it. But the real problem is that the captions are not downloaded properly.

Comment: my problem is getting the CC into one string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this post [How to get "transcript" in youtube-api v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061195/how-to-get-transcript-in-youtube-api-v3/21550325)

You can get them via GET request on: `http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang={LANG}&v={VIDEOID}`

Example:
http://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=-osCkzoL53U

Note that they should have subtitles added, will not work if auto-generated.

Comment: As for me, I ended up with getting the source code of Google2SRT from here http://google2srt.sourceforge.net/en/. There I could find all the required urls and querystrings.

Comment: you can get auto-generated caption as well by appending `&track=asr` in URL but for some of the video, i am also not getting the response.

Comment: Is it possible to get it using the API v3 nuget itself instead of making http calls?

Comment: @AmirNo-Family don't think so, if you are not the owner of the video

Comment: Is it possible to download auto-generated YouTube captions through their API?

Comment: No longer works